# Real time spectrum analyzer display problem

Tags: frequency-spectrum

In real time spectrum analyzers, it is said that data is captured without any loss in time domain and user can see any event that happend in the captured time.

In case of high bandwidth and low frequency resolution, there are too many FFT bins to show on the screen.

How does real time spectrum analyzers handle this problem? Is setting a 30 FPS constant refresh rate a good way to solve this? What about the bins that are not shown?

Comment: *"...high bandwidth and low frequency resolution..."* does not describe *"...many FFT bins to show on the screen..."*...Would it be possible to clarify which are the bins that you perceive as not being shown?

Comment: What I meant by that sentence is, if you take the bandwidth(Also sampling rate) 50 MHz and frequency resolution ~50 KHz, you would get about 1024 sample per FFT bin and 50.000.000/1024 =~ 48800 FFT bins in second. Human eye can not see 48800 FPS so how does this data shown in the graphical interface?